# When JavaFX javafx.scene.control.Labeled element has it's width adjusted to fit the text

Tags: javafx

After I set button's text, it's width property does not change at that moment

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent parent = ...
    ...
    Button component added to the parent
    ...
    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();           
    ...
    Button's width is 30.0
    Button's text is set here
    Button's width still is 30.0
    ...
}
```

Comment: The dimensions won't change until a layout pass occurs.

Comment: I would think that all rendering should have already have happened after  `stage.show()` call. Is there a way I can prematurely initiate "layout pass occurs" after I set button's text?

Comment: No, after you set the text, the width won't change due to the change in text until the *next* layout pass. It would be extremely inefficient if layouts were recomputed every time a single property changed. (Even if you call `setText()` before `show()`, there's no guarantee that a layout occurs before you call `getWidth()`.)  You can call `parent.layout()`, but really the bigger question is why you care about this at all. There should be no reason for anyone except the parent to care about the size of the button.

Comment: The bottom line here is that if you need to know the width of the button, you are almost certainly not doing things the way they were intended.

Comment: "almost certainly not doing things the way they were intended" - probably so

Comment: So why do you think you need to know the button's width?

Comment: After I add buttons (its actually a composite of button and a text field placed in HBox) to a container (VBox) I want all the buttons to have the same width as the button with max width

Comment: So after I set texts to the buttons I try to find the longest button but all buttons have same width

Comment: Either use an appropriately-configured `GridPane`, or write your own `Pane` subclass and do this calculation in `layoutChildren()`

Comment: `layoutChildren()` is a good solution.